# facebook search places by name instead of nearest places

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, android-location

Hey here is the code in which is for placeId by nearest places but I want to take location by its name. Like if I want any location and write its name it will give locations containing name of location because i cant get desired locations if i search by lat and long. I just get some popular locations only.

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Places extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
private Handler mHandler;
private JSONObject location;

protected ListView placesList;
protected LocationManager lm;
protected MyLocationListener locationListener;

protected static JSONArray jsonArray;
final static double TIMES_SQUARE_LAT = 40.756;
final static double TIMES_SQUARE_LON = -73.987;

protected ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    location = new JSONObject();

    setContentView(R.layout.places_list);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String default_or_new = extras.getString("LOCATION");
    if (default_or_new.equals("times_square")) {
        try {
            location.put("latitude", new Double(TIMES_SQUARE_LAT));
            location.put("longitude", new Double(TIMES_SQUARE_LON));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        fetchPlaces();
    } else {
        getLocation();
    }
}

public void getLocation() {
    /*
     * launch a new Thread to get new location
     */
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Places.this, "",
                    getString(R.string.fetching_location), false, true,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            showToast("No location fetched.");
                        }
                    });

            if (lm == null) {
                lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }

            if (locationListener == null) {
                locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
            }

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            if (provider != null && lm.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 0, locationListener,
                        Looper.getMainLooper());
            } else {
                /*
                 * GPS not enabled, prompt user to enable GPS in the
                 * Location menu
                 */
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Places.this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.enable_gps_title)
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.enable_gps))
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.gps_settings,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        startActivityForResult(
                                                new Intent(
                                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS),
                                                0);
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        Places.this.finish();
                                    }
                                }).show();
            }
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /*
     * User returning from the Location settings menu. try to fetch location
     * again.
     */
    dialog.dismiss();
    getLocation();
}

/*
 * Fetch nearby places by providing the search type as 'place' within 1000
 * mtrs of the provided lat & lon
 */
private void fetchPlaces() {
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Places.this, "",
                getString(R.string.nearby_places), true, true,
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        showToast("No places fetched.");
                    }
                });
    }
    /*
     * Source tag: fetch_places_tag
     */
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("type", "place");
    try {
        params.putString("center", location.getString("latitude") + ","
                + location.getString("longitude"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        showToast("No places fetched.");
        return;
    }
    params.putString("distance", "1000");
    Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("search", params,
            new placesRequestListener());
}

/*
 * Callback after places are fetched.
 */
public class placesRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        Log.d("Facebook-FbAPIs", "Got response: " + response);
        dialog.dismiss();

        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("data");
            if (jsonArray == null) {
                showToast("Error: nearby places could not be fetched");
                return;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                placesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.places_list);
                placesList.setOnItemClickListener(Places.this);
                placesList.setAdapter(new PlacesListAdapter(Places.this));
            }
        });

    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        showToast("Fetch Places Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
    if (!Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "You must first log in.");
    } else {
        try {
            final String message = "Check-in from the "
                    + getString(R.string.app_name);
            final String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position)
                    .getString("name");
            final String placeID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position)
                    .getString("id");
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.check_in_title)
                    .setMessage(
                            String.format(getString(R.string.check_in_at),
                                    name))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.checkin,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                /*
                                 * Source tag: check_in_tag Check-in user at
                                 * the selected location posting to the
                                 * me/checkins endpoint. More info here:
                                 * https://developers.facebook
                                 * .com/docs/reference/api/user/ - checkins
                                 */
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                    params.putString("place", placeID);
                                    params.putString("message", message);
                                    params.putString("coordinates",
                                            location.toString());
                                    Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(
                                            "me/checkins", params, "POST",
                                            new placesCheckInListener(),
                                            null);
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                    .show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class placesCheckInListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        showToast("API Response: " + response);
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        showToast("Check-in Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
}

public void showToast(final String msg) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Places.this, msg,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Definition of the list adapter
 */
public class PlacesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Places placesList;

    public PlacesListAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return jsonArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        View hView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.place_item, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
            holder.location = (TextView) hView
                    .findViewById(R.id.place_location);
            hView.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
        try {
            holder.name.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder.name.setText("");
        }
        try {
            String location = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location")
                    .getString("street")
                    + ", "
                    + jsonObject.getJSONObject("location")
                            .getString("city")
                    + ", "
                    + jsonObject.getJSONObject("location").getString(
                            "state");
            holder.location.setText(location);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder.location.setText("");
        }
        return hView;
    }

}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView location;
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (loc != null) {
            try {
                location.put("latitude", new Double(loc.getLatitude()));
                location.put("longitude", new Double(loc.getLongitude()));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
            showToast("Location acquired: "
                    + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()) + " "
                    + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            fetchPlaces();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
}
```

---